# specifiying choice between attribute and content in XML Schema

Tags: xsd

How do you specify in XML Schema, that an element may either have an attribute present, or a content, but not both.

Example:

Here the element `<sig>` can either be expressed as :

```
<sig href="http://static.domain.tld/1231231.sig"/>
```

or having it's content placed inline :

```
<sig>
  8374a32f4c2de
  12B8374a32f4c
  2de12B8374a32
  f4c2de12B8374
  a32f4c2de12bd
</sig>
```

Cheers.

EDIT : typos

Answer (score 0):

Due to my knowledge this is one of the places, where XML Schema is inferior to Relax NG, where
you can specify:

```
    <element name="sig">
        <choice>
            <attribute name="href">
                <data type="anyURI"/>
            </attribute>
            <data type="hexBinary"/>
        </choice>
    </element>
```